# Checking to see if an element exists in a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a recursive function that checks to see whether or not "a" is in an array. I'm trying to take the head of the tail and compare it to "a". However, it doesn't return the correct boolean value every time because it only take the head of the tail once. how do i make this recursive?

```
isElement :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isElement a [] = False
isElement a (x:xs)
  | a == x = True
  | otherwise = False
  where x = head(xs)
```

Comment: You do not need last where expression. You already have x from pattern-matching pattern in function definition. all you need is call your function again in otherwise case

Comment: Call `isElement 2 [1,2,3,4]` and imagine what happens (with a vague model of how evaluation happens in Haskell). line 3: `a=2, x=1, xs=[2,3,4]`. Line 4: `2==1` returns False so move on. Line 5: `otherwise` evaluates to True so we evaluate the expression to the right of the equals sign. Now `x=head [2,3,4]` so `x=2` (if you ever evaluate it) but you evaluate the expression `False` to get `False` and return that.

Comment: `isElement a (x:xs) = a == x || isElement a xs`

Comment: Also, while you’re doing this as an exercise, this already exists as `elem`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. First off, your `where` block is not accomplishing anything. `x` is already known to be the head of the list because it's part of the `(x:xs)` construct, which destructures the list directly into the variables. So that line can be entirely removed. Second, there's no actual recursion here. You need to call `isElement` in the false case to check the rest of the list, rather than simply returning `False`.

```
isElement :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isElement a [] = False
isElement a (x:xs)
  | a == x = True
  | otherwise = isElement a xs
```

Note that compiling your program with `-Wall` will give you warnings about a lot of things, including unused variables. In particular, the fact that, in your example (after removing the `where` block), `xs` was an unused variable should be a red flag and, in this case, gives us some insight into the problem: you never used the rest of the list, so the rest of the list gets ignored.